# Avoid 'Press ENTER to continue' in Vim when entering man pages

Tags: vim, manpage

When I am editing C files, I want to use `K` key to open man pages directly and then press `q` inside the man pages to quit and go back straight to Vim. Every time I do that, I see `Press ENTER to continue`, which I would like to avoid.

How do I do that?

What I've tried: using `silent`, setting `cmdheight` to 2 - none of these solved the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you only want to skip this message for man pages, this should do :

```
:nnoremap K K<CR>
:vnoremap K K<CR>
```